# Unable to create a new project collection in TFS 2012. Currently I am using 2008 R2 SQL express data base version

Tags: tfs

Getting Below Error ! while creating a new project collection. Actually as we are using 2008 R2 Sql expression edition, size per database is only 10GB. Current we reached this limit. How to handle this situation

> TF255374: The following SQL Server instance is not compatible with Team Foundation Server: ABSSVR\SqlExpress. The default collation is set to Latin1_General_CI_AI. Team Foundation Server requires that the default collation be case insensitive and accent sensitive. You must choose a SQL Server instance whose default collation settings match these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run the following code in **visual studio command prompt** to fix the issue, the code can change the sql collation to support collation **Latin1_General_CI_AS**.

(Change the INSTANCENAME and password accordingly, or use your admin account instead of SA.)

```
Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=TFSSQL /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=sa /SAPWD=pass@word1 /SQLCOLLATION=Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Comment: @Jai Have you resolved your issue by above workaround? any update for this?